# Unresolved support library imports after updating to 3.1.1

Tags: android-studio

I have just updated to Android Studio 3.1.1, and now all my support library related imports are shown as broken (see screenshot attached), even though the app successfully builds and can be installed on a device. Is there a way to fix this? Thanks.

[image: No support library]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem also

and resolved it by using support version 27.1.1.

Comment: @PaulR sorry, but this is the answer on the question and issuer confirmed it.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, using support library version `27.1.1` fixed the problem.

Thanks, whoever commented and then deleted their comment - good thing I noticed it :)